# Flexslider works on my computer but doesn't load after uploading online

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexslider

As the title suggests, I am currently using Flexslider by WooThemes on a [site](http://johnjuy.com/go/) I am creating.

It is not on there but it does work when I am loading it from the files on my computer. Here is a screenshot of how it loads (properly) on my computer:

[image: image as seen loading from fils on my computer]

I know that the JavaScript works because other scripts are working just fine. (parallax, smooth scrolling, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your problem is in double jQuery loading. You include jquery in `<head>` and in `<footer>`. Remove one of them.

Comment: It was the double loading. I didn't realize that it was at the bottom as well. Thanks, maximkou!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to get a tool such as Firebug for Firefox, and to learn how to work it.

When visiting the site, with the Firebug "Console" tab active, this error is immediately visible:

```
TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
$('.flexslider').flexslider();
```

This may be telling you one of two things:

1. jQuery can't be run via the `$` function name (which is true in many instances in WP.  See point #5 in this article: http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)
2. The flexslider js file isn't loading (which, in fact, it is)

So, change your code from:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });
    </script>
```

To:

```
    <script>
        jQuery(window).load(function($) {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });
    </script>
```

And it should work.